# Numbering group results into unique identifiers

Tags: sql-server-2008

I am trying to create an query that results in unique identifiers (account number).

What I need to achieve is for each unique entry into Col1 to create a another row number / UI.

I have been attempting this with the below query

```
elect  col1,col2 ,(DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY col1,col2))  as UI from [TABLE]
```

and this is what i have been getting:

```html
col1 col2 UI
34 1 1
1973 448 2
355 3924 3
18709 8168 4
5201 9211 5
5762 9294 6
3864 10669 7
4914 12568 8
4914 12569 9
42465 921  10
```

but i need it to look like this:

```html
col1 col2 UI
34 1 1
1973 448 2
355 3924 3
18709 8168 4
5201 9211 5
5762 9294 6
3864 10669 7
4914 12568 8
4914 12569 8
42465 921  9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a way to - more loosely - rank col2 e.g. using division

```
select
   col1,col2 
  ,DENSE_RANK() OVER( ORDER BY col1,col2/10)  as newUI 
from mytable


+----+-------+-------+-------+
|    | col1  | col2  | newUI |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |    34 |     1 |     1 |
|  2 |   355 |  3924 |     2 |
|  3 |  1973 |   448 |     3 |
|  4 |  3864 | 10669 |     4 |
|  5 |  4914 | 12568 |     5 |
|  6 |  4914 | 12569 |     5 |
|  7 |  5201 |  9211 |     6 |
|  8 |  5762 |  9294 |     7 |
|  9 | 18709 |  8168 |     8 |
| 10 | 42465 |   921 |     9 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+
```